# python: Detecting a negative number within a string

Tags: python, string

So I have a number of text files with a line like this:

```
STRT .M                 -9.0:  START DEPTH
```

I wish to detect the negative number and replace it with 0.1.

I can detect the negative number, simply by looking for the '-'

```
text.count('-')
```

if text.count('-') > 0, there is a negative number.

My question is: How do I replace '-9.0' in the string that with the number 0.1? Ultimately, I want to output:

```
STRT .M                  0.1:  START DEPTH
```

Comment: Note: the negative number varies between files. It's not always -9.0.

Comment: Is this fixed-width? (i.e., does it matter if the replacement doesn't have as many characters as the original?)

Comment: No, it could be -9.0, -10.1, -11.123, etc. so I need a general solution for replacing any negative decimal number with 0.1.

Comment: Let me clarify: if I replace a number like "-100000" with "0.1" and don't add any extra spaces, does it matter that the rest of the line won't be in the same place as before?

Comment: @Tim Yates I don't think it would matter, but I am not 100% sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simple solution is to user `.replace('-9.0','0.1')` ([see documentation for `.replace()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)), but I think you need more flexible solution based on regular expressions:

```
import re
new_string = re.sub(r'-\d+\.\d+', '0.1', your_string)
```

Comment: Agreed. I should have been more clear. The negative number could be any negative number.

Comment: @Flux Can it be also integer?

Comment: Good question. I doubt it would be an integer, but I cannot be 100% sure since I have not looked through each of the ~200 files.

Comment: @bradley.ayers You are right - I posted it before I tested it. Now it replaces every negative float with decimal part consisting at least of 1 digit (does not match eg. `.5`).

Comment: Shouldn't the regex include a '-' in front of the decimals?!

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you are working with LAS files. You can check out [libLAS](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/libLAS) to see if it works for you. And here is a [tutorial](http://trac.liblas.org/wiki/PythonTutorial).

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions can do this:

```
>>> import re
>>> regex = re.compile(r' -\d+(\.\d+)?:')
>>> regex.sub(' 0.1:', 'STRT .M                 -9.0:  START DEPTH')
'STRT .M                 0.1:  START DEPTH'
>>> regex.sub(' 0.1:', 'STRT .M                 -19.01:  START DEPTH')
'STRT .M               0.1:  START DEPTH'
>>> regex.sub(' 0.1:', 'STRT .M                 -9:  START DEPTH')
'STRT .M                 0.1:  START DEPTH'
```

[`re.sub` documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub)

Comment: Will this work if the negative number is ANY negative number and not just -9.0?

Comment: Note that this wouldn't work for, e.g., `-10.0`, much less `-9` (no decimal place). The fix is simple if it isn't fixed-width, but the OP hasn't specified...

Comment: It has been [revised](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6132632/revisions) and now seems to be able to do just that.